# get array of KEYS for each element under jsonarray

Tags: android, json, arraylist, iterator, arrays

I want to parse my Json array dynamically. and want to get array of KEYS for each element under jsonarray. i an getting this through iterator. but not getting the sequeance as per the output json formate.

**my JSON Formate :**

```
{
  "result": "Success",
  "AlertDetails": [
    {
      "ShipmentNumber": "SHP34",
      "Customer": "BEST",
      "DateCreated": "2012-08-29T04:59:18Z"
      "CustomerName": "BEST"
    },
    {
      "ShipmentNumber": "SHP22",
      "Customer": "BEST",
      "DateCreated": "2012-08-29T05:34:18Z"
      "CustomerName": "Jelly"
    }
  ]
}
```

**here is My Code :**

```
    JSONArray array = jsonobject.getJSONArray("AlertDetails");

    JSONObject keyarray = array.getJSONObject(0);
    Iterator temp = keyarray.keys();
        while (temp.hasNext()) {
                    String curentkey = (String) temp.next();
                    KEYS.add(curentkey);

    }
Log.d("Parsing Json class", "  ---- KEYS---- " + KEYS);
```

**What i am getting in logcate output:**

```
 ---- KEYS---- [DateCreated,CustomerName, Customer, ShipmentNumber]
```

**What i want :**

```
 ---- KEYS---- [ShipmentNumber, Customer, DateCreated,CustomerName]
```

Comment: @LazyNinja no it's just a name.

Comment: @LazyNinja Yes it is an arraylist. can you please help me to get out of this? would be great if you give me suggestions for this issue.

Comment: Dont anybody told you that JSON object doesnt follow any specific ordering...the both output is equall as per the json format...now the question is why u want that in that particular format??

Comment: @MKJParekh:thnx for your Support. but i want to Display each KEY Name in my Screen as Column Name in same Formate that i am getting it From the WS Response. the KEYS are Not known to me in Advance.

Comment: Then add one more thing in your WS Response..a JSON object with key name with value as their index ID 1, NAME 2 DATE 3..so so... and decide upon that...

Comment: Or you can convert your WS from JSON to XML or SOAP. That would be fine too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The JSONObject documentation (link: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) has the following description for the `keys()` function:

> public Iterator keys ()
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> Returns an iterator of the String names in this object. The returned
>   iterator supports remove, which will remove the corresponding mapping
>   from this object. If this object is modified after the iterator is
>   returned, the iterator's behavior is undefined. **The order of the keys
>   is undefined**.

So you may get the keys but the order is undefined. You may use any of the sorting algorithms if you want the keys in any particular order.

**EDIT**

Since you are unaware of the order of KEYS you are getting from the WS, after receiving the data you may show the details on screen in an ordered format . After building the `arraylist` `KEYS`, you may sort it alphabetically using the following:

```
Collections.sort(KEYS);
```

This will order the `Strings` in the `KEYS` `arraylist` according to its *natural ordering* (which is *alphabetically*).

Comment: Thnx for your Support. can you suggest me any of the Algorithm to solve this problem and that can give me the Arraylist that has same KEYS order that i am getting in Response from WS?

Answer (score 6):

I just come to know when I press *ctlr+space bar*, in which its clearly written that behavior of the *keys* is undefined, orders is not maintain by *keys.*

[image]

*Arun George* said@ correctly that you have to use any sorting method to achieve your goal.

and for sorting may be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051785/when-jsonobject-keys-are-iterate-it-is-not-in-the-same-order-as-in-response-from) will help you.

Answer (score 6):

Use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library from google. It has a a lot of setting to read/create/parse json array and json objects. I didn't test it to find the solution, but I think it's very simple and full featured tool and can solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use different library to parse json dynamically.

Below I wrote a piece of code based on Jackson JSON Processor, which is the best JSON library in my opinion

```
public void test() throws IOException {
    String str = "{\n" +
            "  \"result\": \"Success\",\n" +
            "  \"AlertDetails\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"ShipmentNumber\": \"SHP34\",\n" +
            "      \"Customer\": \"BEST\",\n" +
            "      \"DateCreated\": \"2012-08-29T04:59:18Z\",\n" +
            "      \"CustomerName\": \"BEST\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}";

    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    JsonParser jsonParser = factory.createJsonParser(str);

    JsonToken jsonToken;
    SerializedString alertDetails = new SerializedString("AlertDetails");
    while (!jsonParser.nextFieldName(alertDetails)) { /* move to AlertDetails field */ }

    jsonParser.nextToken(); // skip [ start array
    jsonParser.nextToken(); // skip { start object
    // until } end object
    while ((jsonToken = jsonParser.nextToken()) != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        if (jsonToken == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            System.out.println(jsonParser.getCurrentName());
        }
    }

}
```

It simply prints out field names in the same order as in json:

```
ShipmentNumber
Customer
DateCreated
CustomerName
```

---

**EDIT**

Naturally you can use other libraries like gson etc. But remember, as is written on [json.org](http://json.org), that:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

and the order of keys depends on implementation and might vary in each request.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the method [names();](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names%28%29)

> Returns an array containing the string names in this object.

Edit: returns names in undefined order. Suggestions: parse it on your own

Comment: yes you are right.i have also tried it but that is also giving me same Undefined order of KEYS that i am getting with using key() Method. would be very great full if you have any More Suggestion to solve it out this issues.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you parse it on your own