# change the order of json values

Tags: json

I have a json data as follows

```
[{
  "_id": "52cbafc5afcec877d925d116",
  "id": "52",
  "url": "172.34.56.7"
}, {
  "_id": "52c255e5cf0060b8cce84b4a",
  "id": "13",
  "url": "172.18.2.114"
}, {
  "_id": "52cbd018afcec877d925d131",
  "id": "49",
  "url": "172.16.2.120"
}, {
  "_id": "52d60c9eafcec877d925d17a",
  "id": "100",
  "url": "156.45.34.56"
}]
```

I want to print the data as below.(last data comes first)

```
[{
    "_id": "52d60c9eafcec877d925d17a",
    "id": "100",
    "url": "156.45.34.56"
  }, {
    "_id": "52cbd018afcec877d925d131",
    "id": "49",
    "url": "172.16.2.120"
  }, {
    "_id": "52c255e5cf0060b8cce84b4a",
    "id": "13",
    "url": "172.18.2.114"
  },
  [{
    "_id": "52cbafc5afcec877d925d116",
    "id": "52",
    "url": "172.34.56.7"
  }]
```

How it is possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [When JsonObject's keys are iterated they aren't in the same order as in the response from the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051785/when-jsonobjects-keys-are-iterated-they-arent-in-the-same-order-as-in-the-resp)

Comment: You'd would modify the data structure before you create the JSON, or after you parsed the JSON, but you'd never directly edit the JSON. We can only help you if you tell us which programming languages you use to create/parse the JSON. To be clear: This problem has **nothing** to do with JSON, but with how to sort collections in the language you are creating or parsing the JSON with.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a Comparator and then sort your Json array with it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using

```
data=data.reverse()
```