# How to get JSONObject values in correct / listed order?

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

Im using `Iterator<String> _names  = _formObject.keys();` to get the values from the following json but values i got are not arranged in correct order ,for eg i got in the order of "Name,No,Phone,Sex", how can i get the correct values as it in json?

```
{ "form" :{         
            "No" : {
                "type" : "text"
                  },
            "phone" : {
                "type" : "text"

            },
            "Name" : {
                "type" : "text"
            },
            "Sex" : {
                "type" : "radio"

             }
         }
       }
```

Comment: its based on your response.

Comment: JSON has no notion of order for object member keys (RFC 7159, section 4)

Comment: @Achilles I stored my json in my file storage . then only i parse it .so there is no chance of parsing based on response.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051785/when-jsonobjects-keys-are-iterated-they-arent-in-the-same-order-as-in-the-resp

Answer (score 4):

There is *no* "correct order" with Key-Value Pairs in a [JSON](http://json.org) Object. However, if you manually process the JSON Reader, you will read the serialized order - this approach works because the stream is handled *before* it is *reconstructed* into an object graph (that uses a Map for JSONObject internally).

To access the *raw* JSON reader, see [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) - however, be aware that there is *no guarantee* that any *equivalent* JSON that you get is supplied in this order! While it "will work", it creates a false brittleness based upon one (of many) equivalent JSON outputs.

See the accepted answer in [When JsonObject's keys are iterated they aren't in the same order as in the response from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051785/when-jsonobjects-keys-are-iterated-they-arent-in-the-same-order-as-in-the-resp):

> The order of the keys of a JSON object is not supposed to be meaningful. **If you want a specific order, you should use an array, not an object**.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(result != null)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject jobj = result.getJSONObject("result");

                String status = jobj.getString("status");

                if(status.equals("true"))
                {
                    JSONArray array = jobj.getJSONArray("data");

                    for(int x = 0; x < array.length(); x++)
                    {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put("name", array.getJSONObject(x).getString("header"));

                        map.put("date", array.getJSONObject(x).getString("date"));

                        map.put("description", array.getJSONObject(x).getString("description"));

                        list.add(map);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Calendar.this, "Network Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

it is reading from the given JSON

```
{
result: {
   data: [
  {
    header: "En övre rubrik här",
    date: "10 Apr,2014",
     description: "Test av en fin text. Om jag länkar. www.swerix.se Mer annat kanske.   0706300080 "
  },
  {
    header: "Info 3",
   date: "17 Apr,2014",
   description: "Detta är en ny information. Skrivet över även hej hopp"
  },
  {
  header: "testing news1",
  date: "13 Mar,2014",
  description: "this is testing news description12"
  }
  ],
  status: "true",
  description: "Data found"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this-

```
Iterator<String> _names  = _formObject.keys();
        while (_names.hasNext()) {
            String key = _names.next();
            try {
                Object value = _formObject.get(key);
                if(value.equals("No"))
                { /*Do your stuff for No*/ }

                if(value.equals("phone"))
                { /*Do your stuff for phone*/ }

                if(value.equals("Name"))
                { /*Do your stuff for Name*/ }

                if(value.equals("Sex"))
                { /*Do your stuff for Sex*/ }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
        }
```

So it doesn't matter in which order they appeared before. All you have to do is to check which key do you want in which order with `_formObject.get(key)`.

Please note that `keys()` function on a `jsonObject` doesn't give the ordered list as it is.
You have to do it as suggested in this way.